# Profanities filter

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hay guys. I try to make a profanities filter. I already have one what is looks like:

```
for(x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
  if(message.content.toUpperCase() == profanities[x].toUpperCase()) {
    message.channel.send('Hey! Don\'t say that!')
    message.delete();
    return;
  }
}
```

But this delete the whole msg. I wanna make one what just filter out the profanities and i made this:

```
for(x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
var msg2 = message.content.toUpperCase().includes(profanities[x]).toUpperCase()
  if (msg2) {
    while (msg2) {
      censor(msg, profanities[x].toUpperCase(), ';)')
    }
    message.channel.send(msg)
    message.delete();
    return;
  }
}
```

Vars and funs what maybe important:

```
var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();

function censor(text, toChange, newWord) {


var toReturn = text;
while (toReturn.includes(toChange)) {
    toReturn = toReturn.replace(toChange, newWord);
}


return toReturn;
}`var profanities = require('profanities');`
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Oh some a part of the msg loss.. So.. I just figure out why the 2nd part dosn't work and i hoped someone can help me out whats the problem with this

Answer (score 4):

Impossible, You cannot edit a users message through a Discord bot. You can delete the message and send it without profanity through the bot

Comment: Actually not imposible.. Just u need the user's name and pasword.. But yeah i wanna make something what do this

Comment: *"Actually not imposible.. Just u need the user's name and pasword"* 10/10

Answer (score 0):

A profanity filter is actually quite easy to create. Just use this code!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'XXXXXXXXX'; //Token (DO NOT SHARE WITH OTHERS!!!)

client.login(token);

client.on('message', message => {

    var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();

    // Profanity Filter //
    if(msg.includes('PROFAIN WORD HERE')) { //Checks message for profanity
        message.delete(); //Deletes the message
        message.author.send(message.author + ', PLEASE DO NOT USE PROFANITY. YOU WILL BE TEMPORARILY MUTED ASAP.') //Sends warning to user in DM
    }
});
```

If you want the code to work, *always* keep the msg.includes word capitalized. Having any lowercase in the word or phrase will not make the code work.

Comment: This only deletes the message. Editing other users' messages through a bot is currently unsupported. This code is all I could think of.